# How to lexically detect sql SELECT queries?

Tags: java, sql

I want to detect if any sql string expects a return value based on a `SELECT`, or not.

```
boolean isSelectStatement(sql) {
   return !sql.startsWith(sql, "INSERT"
         && !sql.startsWith(sql, "UPDATE")
         && !sql.startsWith("DELETE");
}
```

The following would thereby be detected as select statement, which is true:

```
DECLARE @request_id = '10'; SELECT @request_id as foo;
```

Would you think it is sufficient to detect any non-SELECT statements therefore? Are there any definitions out that show any type of possible SELECT statements? Or even libraries that can determine if a sql is select, or not?

Comment: Your SQL fragment which is supposed to be classified as a select in fact begins with `DECLARE`.  That aside, an `INSERT` statement can contain a select inside it, so your logic may be more complicated than you think.

Comment: A query may also start with `WITH` and can be anything: SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE..

Comment: Also the query could be in the form (SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) so it starts with round bracket (so if you will play with white-list instead of black-list you're also in a complicate position). Probably you can solve your task differently: for example to make a dedicated database user and grant him only the restricted set of privileges.

Comment: There's a whole other lot of commands (DECLARE being one of them; that's two statements in your sample), which may depend on the database the queries target. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-commands.html)'s the list for PostgreSQL 11 for instance. I suggest you leverage an existing parser

Comment: @membersound . . . At the very least, you should tag your question with the database you are using.  You are allowing multiple statements in the string, so there is really no connection between the first statement and what executing the string will return.

Comment: If I understood well, You could give a try of:: !sql.Contains ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)'s a list of ANTLR grammars which contain grammars for multiple database dialects (plsql, tsql, sqlite, mysql). If you're familiar with [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) this should make solving the task a breeze.